# VBA Message Box Curency Formatting

Tags: excel, format, msgbox, vba

I'm new to VBA (Excel). I'm trying to make a revenue calculator that appears in a message box after the user inputs the cost of the product and how many were sold. How do you create a generic currency format for the concatenated variable 'revenue'?
For example, my problem is that when I make the format "$0,000.00", but the revenue is only 40, it shows up as "0,040.00", when i really just want "$40.00"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Format function.

```
MsgBox Format(Amount, "$0.00")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem :)
In VBA you can do all the calculation in Double type and when you get to the MsgBox, you can write `"$" & YourVariable`
Else, if you simply address your MsgBox to display a value in a cell, you could store that value in a Double variable and do what I explained above.